# How did my textbook simplify this equation?

Tags: abstract-algebra

So my textbook has a proof examples and it simplified this line:

$$(2\cdot 3^k + 3(-2)^k) + 6(2\cdot 3^{k-1} + 3(-2)^{k-1})$$
into 
$$3^{k-1}(2\cdot 3 + 6\cdot2) + (3(-2) + 6\cdot 3)(-2)^{k-1}$$

?

Comment: What is $x$? $x = k - 1$?

Comment: I made the modifications you indicated (writing $k-1$ for $x$ everywhere).

Comment: Oh I thought I wrote at the bottom but yeah x is k-1. and thanks MPW

Comment: You did write it at the bottom, but I removed that line after making the change.

Answer (score 1):

$$(2\cdot 3^k + 3(-2)^k) + 6(2\cdot 3^{k-1} + 3(-2)^{k-1}) = 2\cdot 3^k + 3(-2)^k + 6 \cdot 2\cdot 3^{k-1} + 6 \cdot 3(-2)^{k-1}$$
Now, just put $3^{k-1}$ in evidence where has $3^k$ or $3^{k-1}$ and put in evidence $(-2)^{k-1}$ in evidence where has $(-2)^k$ or $(-2)^{k-1}$:

$$3^{k-1}(2\cdot 3 + 6\cdot2) + (3(-2) + 6\cdot 3)(-2)^{k-1}$$

Answer (score 0):

Just note that $(-2)^k=-2\cdot (-2)^{k-1}$ and likewise $3^k=3\cdot 3^{k-1}$.